# Why is my ASP.NET MVC project saving several copies of itself?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

This is really weird behavior, let's say I have an asp.net mvc project as follow on my desktop (vista):

/mvcapplication/app1

then over the course of development, I copy this solution to a briefcase on a thumbdrive so I can work on it from a laptop (xp).

When I insert the thumbdrive back on the desktop, I notice it's taking longer and longer to sync, eventually it took so long that it just hangs there. I checked the project structure and found that it is now:

/mvcapplication/app1/app1/app1/app1

with each /app1 containing the entire project structures. I am not new to visual studio, and I am sure I opened and saved the solution and files just as I normally did, but this is just bizzard. I thought this is caused by briefcase, but the same thing happened when I  copied the solution into a folder on the thumbdrive.

I would have left this alone, but with that sort of crazy folder structure it's really difficult to determine which folder has my current changes..

Anyone ever run into something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Never had this happen but then I don't use the Briefcase.  Then again, I try to avoid most things in Vista.

I just use good 'ol copy and past for thumb drive stuff.