# An .ascx user control page opens up as hex?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, user-controls

I am not sure if this is related to this weird behavior I'm experiencing: [Why is my ASP.NET MVC project saving several copies of itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229811/why-is-my-asp-net-mvc-project-saving-several-copies-of-itself)

But I'm completely stumped.

My solution (asp.net mvc application) currently resides on the thumbdrive (cruzer micro 4gb), all the files were fine as of last night, this morninig I open one of a .ascx, and God almighty, it loads itself into the hex editor, why? what the heck?

I open this same user control in notepad and it's full of crazy random characters.

Somehow it turns itself, a plain text file, into a binary file?

Anyone run into this? I don't have backup (my fault, I should know better), is this reversable?

Comment: Looks like you don't have your solution on the thumbdrive anymore...:(

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you saved the file and somehow triggered a different encoding to be used.

I believe I've seen something similar a couple of times.

Does it compile anyway? If not then it's not readable by VS either and you're probably screwed.

Comment: Yes the solution still compiles. The page displays, but the section that contains the .ascx shows random characters. I worked on it last night, save normally. Humm...if a different encoding was triggered somehow, it surely was un-beknown to me.